# About PATH in FTS alfresco queries

Tags: solr, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco 4.1.6 and SOLR 1.4.

For search, I use fts_alfresco_language and the searchService.query method.

And in my query I search by PATH, TYPE and some custom properties like direction, telephone, mail, or similar.

I have now over 2 millions of documents, and we can see how the performance of the searchs are worst than at the beginning.

I read that in version 1.4 of solr, using PATH on the query is a bad idea. And is better avoid it and only use TYPE and the property key and value.

But I have 2 questions...

1. Why the PATH increase the response time? It's not a help? I have over 1000 main folders at the root of the repository. If I specify the folder that solr may search, why this not filter the results and give me a worst time response than if I don't specify this? Or there are another way to say to solr the main folder to reduce results and then do the rest of the query?
2. When I find by custom properties, I use 3 or 4 properties, all indexed, to search. These merged lookups has a higher overhead than one? Maybe is better to search only by one property, and not by the 3? Or maybe use ORs and not ANDs to quickly results? How works SOLR?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're on an Alfresco Enterprise release, why not just ring up Alfresco support and ask them for help? They're the experts in this!

Comment: Well, I prefer to ask here and know the opinion of developers who meets with this problem. I imagine there are various responses of the problem and I want to know more points of view, and talk about this not only for me, for the knowledge of people that reads this forum too. I'm sure that a lot of people meets with this problem, and need to search inside a specific path but reads that puts the path on the query isn't a good idea. I like to know the reason, and a alternative to search inside a path if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First let me start with this, I'm not sure what you want of this question cause it's vague. You're not asking how to make your query better, your asking why a bad-practice(bad-performance) is working bad for you.

Do some research on how to structure your ECM system, first thing what makes your ECM any good is a proper Content Model. There are books out there which will help you.

If you're structuring your content with folders (Path) and these are important for you, than you need to add these as metadata to your content. If you haven't done that, then you should start with that.

A good Content Model will be able to find content wherever it's placed within your ECM system.
Sure it's easy to migrate a filesystem to an ECM system and just leave it there, but you've done only half the work.

The path queries are slow in general cause it uses a loop pattern and it's expensive. It has been greatly improved in the new SOLR, but it still isn't as fast as normal metadata querying.

Comment: Oks, thanks, Tahir. Well, in fact, I want to make my query better. Is the reason I want to confirm if use PATH, TYPE and metadata on the same query is a bad practice. I read that PATH is a bad idea, but only want to know the reason. You explain it: "use a loop patterns and it's expensive". I imagined the following scenario... I want to search a man with a red shirt, and he lives on a very large street with millions of houses. I don't understand how is possible that "search the man with the red shirt in this street" is faster than "search the man with the red shirt in this house".

Comment: In other words... Saying to Alfresco the path where he can search the element can reduce the places to search, from a million of odds to a hundred of them. Even the loop patterns, I can't imagine how isn't faster.

Comment: yeah but like I said, you need to fix your content model. Just update your content model of man with an extra property house, then run one fix on your current system which loops through your entire repo and adds the house as an extra metadata field on the man. The next time, you just need to search Type:man and shirt:red and house:streetx. The second thing is to fix your solution so the next time a man comes into a house to add the metadata automatically ;)

Comment: Oks, thanks! I understand. I try to explain our case. Our users can put the documents where he wants, specifying a path on a parameter. But with a restriction. The first part of the path will be userCode/year/month and the rest of the path is free, creating the subfolders that they want. Before upload the document, I search if a specific metadata that is unique exists and then, I validate if this path exists, and create it if not. Maybe exists all the path, or a part of it.

Comment: I search the metadata with the query and without PATH: like we talked before, no problem. I can add a metadada on my content model with this userCode and use this metadada on my query. By this way the results are more restrictive without using the PATH. :)

Comment: But for the second task, create the path if not exists... I position the pointer on a node, and ask on each folder if the new folder exists. And go to the children or create it, depends. I use for that the alfresco api, for position the node, and iterate inside the childs. Imagine now that I add a metadata on my content model on each node with the path. The api is faster than if I use search query, or is better use a query on each folder to find if this exists with a same name?

Comment: Oh, and one more question... I don't use aspects on my content model yet. I'm reading that I can use aspects on a query. Doing this give me the results faster? For example, if I have on my model 3 metadates: A, B and C. And in my query I search by A:value AND B:value AND C:value, is better and faster if I group these 3 metadates on an aspect and I search: (@asp\\A:value AND @asp\\B:value @asp\\C:value)?